# Why Qt remove QFtp library start from Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I just want to know why Qt remove [QFtp](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qftp.html) start from Qt version 5.

Of course I can still install [QtFtp](https://github.com/qt/qtftp) manually on Qt5 but I cannot find any official answer about why they remove this library. For now, I should use [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), but it's having limited feature.

Thank you!

---

**Edit:**

More explanation about this sentence "... I should use QNetworkAccessManager, but it's having limited feature."

For example, I [can get list of the content](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qftp.html#list) from FTP server using QtFtp, but I cannot do this with QNetworkAccessManager.

---

Comment: Re. `"...I should use QNetworkAccessManager, but it's having limited feature"`: please edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do and which particular features you think are missing.

Comment: `Why Qt remove QFtp library start from Qt5?` because the design of QFtp was considered to be flawed.

Comment: @t.niese Can you give me more details about that? Can it break our code or is it for security reasons?

Comment: @tirzasrwn: FTP as a protocol itself is deeply flawed. Implementing it properly and in a somewhat robust way is quite difficult. And in this day and age nobody should use it anymore at all. I repeat: _**Do not use FTP!**_ The FTP protocol itself is insecure (no encryption, passwords transmitted in the clear), due to its split channel operation a nightmare to connection track on NAT gateways and firewalls, and overall also doesn't scale well.

Comment: @datenwolf: there is SFTP for encryption. FTP is a great tool with no direct modern replacement, we use it at work, and I don't see it going away any time soon.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: SFTP is a very different protocol and shares no commonalities with "ye olde" FTP. Legacy FTP is a byzantine construction consisting of a control connection, and for every transfer has the server create a "reverse" data connection to the client. Due to these data connections coming in from the opposite end every firewall and NAT router along the way must be able to tap into the control connection in order to punch the necessary port forwards *in-situ*. Also because of this design you can't encrypt traditional FTP (unless you're willing to discriminate NATs and firewalls).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: There've been made additions to FTP – like passive mode, or resuming transfers – that alleviate the problems with the protocol. But all in all FTP is a horribly bad designed protocol and a menace to network engineers all around. There are numerous replacement protocols that have a cleaner design, easier implementation, make better use of the network and are more secure.

Comment: @datenwolf, thanks for the detailed explanation! I didn't know these bits. I also googled a bit and realized I made a mistake, I meant FTPS, not SFTP which is based on SSH (whoever came up with that abbreviation - great naming, pal!). I'm sure there are better protocols, but it's like that xkcd comic about 13 incompatible standards. FTP / SFTP is the standard that works and is supported in many places and many systems where you need file transfer and file browsing functionality.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: FTPS with an encrypted control channel doesn't work via connections that go through a port filter / firewall or NAT. Unless your connection to the internet does not happen to utilize some form of firewall / filter rules *and* IPv6 (since IPv4 most likely will put you behind CGNAT) most likely FTPS with a secured command channel will not work. Also on servers FTP doesn't come by default these days, and takes significant extra effort to set up. SSH/SFTP, however, will work right out of the box for Linux and BSDs and little effort on Windows servers.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: For some unfathomable reason semi-/professional digital cameras that support direct to network uploads still use FTP. I don't get it. Why not simply use rsync, which would be far better suited for the use case.